# How to check char * "length" before I use string functions in C?

Tags: c, string

I want to check C string length and if it is valid (`\0` termination).

So far I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char good_str[32] = "123456789012345";  // 15 chars with `\0` is ok
char bad_str[32]  = "1234567890123456"; // 16 chars with `\0` is too long

int check_max_len(char * s, int max_len){
    for (int i = 0; i < max_len; i++) {
        if (s[i] == 0) 
            return 0; // not too long
    }
    return 1; // too long or no `\0`
}

int main() {
    
    int is_bad;
    
    is_bad = check_max_len((char*)&good_str, 16);
    printf("Good string: %i\n", is_bad);
    
    is_bad = check_max_len((char*)&bad_str, 16);
    printf("Bad string: %i\n", is_bad);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I guess this will work well for my application, but maybe there are some "industry standards", or some function in standard library for that?

Comment: `memchr()` will give you faster results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Portable way to check if a char\* pointer is a null-terminated string](//stackoverflow.com/q/28165464/90527)", "[Checking validity of non null-terminated string](//stackoverflow.com/q/35329617/90527)"

Comment: On POSIX systems you have `strnlen`.

Comment: @outis Not exactly.

Comment: But as SparKot points out, `memchr(buf, 0, max_len) != NULL` is equivalent and more portable.

Comment: Why `(char*)&good_str` / `bad_str` and not just `good_str` / `bad_str`?  I have to say I don't understand that.  Also, you should be `const` qualifying function parameters and variables that don't need  to be mutable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard function `strnlen()` from the `string.h` header file which comes fairly close to functionality you are looking for. It takes 2 parameters: a `string` (const char*) and a `maximum read length` (size_t) respectively.

It looks like this:

```c
size_t strnlen(const char* str, size_t max_len);
```

It will return the quantity of bytes pointed to by the passed string, excluding the terminating null character if encountered within the the passed `max_len`.

---

Logically speaking, this function still requires you to know the expected string length so that way you can have an accurate results. Without that information, your program will error out or it will do unexpected things such as reading into other strings, and data. Hence why you should make it clear that you expect null terminated strings to begin with.

Comment: "but doesn't compare it to a maximum value.": But that's the whole point of what OP needs.  `strlen` isn't safe here because if the null terminator isn't there, `strlen` would overrun the array.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't want to argue, but as long as the strings vary in length and OP doesn't know the expected length, there is no way to be `safe` (or at least "safer"). If we give a length to `strnlen`, who knows if the string passed will fit in the allotted checking area or not.